# Alternative autoregistration on C++ (due -nostartfiles)

Tags: c++, g++

Assume use case where central 'controller' needs run various clients using unified interface. Each client is implemented in separate .cpp file (module). Functionality of each client is unknown to the controller.
There is known trick to make each module register its client automatically:

MyClient1.cpp

```
#include "client_inter"
class MyClient1 : public IClient
{ ... }
static MyClient1 client;
static int regStatus = register_client(&client);
```

Function **register_client** is implemented somewhere within 'controller'. It is automatically invoked by global initializer and thus module introduces its client(s) to the controller without being directly known by the controller.

It all worked nicely until recently the **-nostartfiles** switch was added into our GCC build infrastructure. Now global initializer is not running and therefore 'register_client' is not invoked and a client is not registered within the controller.

While I'm trying to remove this switch from the build, I may need alternative way (even GCC-specific) to have same functionality.

The problem is that there are many clients and they not always present in build (it depends on target and configuration). Therefore I don't want that the controller will know all of them. Or let it "know" them all, but missing symbols would not break linking.

Comment: You effectively disabled run-time initialization of all global objects. What was the goal you were trying to achieve?

Comment: `-nostartfiles` is specifically designed to leave out certain standard functionality that your code and close to all code relies on. If I were you, I would not bother with a workaround. Whoever added that switch to your build infrastructure made a grave mistake. Focus on getting *that* fixed.

Comment: As I said I am trying to make it go away. Unfortunately in big corporates it is not always depends solely on you.